# Problem with luatex fontspec and flowfram

Tags: flowfram, fixltx2e

The following minimial example produces a correct output on an older miktex system (using lualatex) ie. the figure which doesn't fit into the last frame on page 1 flows into the first frame on page 2. On a new version of miktex there is a problem, the figure flows into the dynamic header frame and completely messes up the page. I was wondering if anybody had a quick solution to this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[draft]{flowfram}
\ffvadjustfalse
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\makedfheaderfooter
\Ncolumn{3}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setdynamiccontents*{header}{Test}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

XXX

\begin{figure}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}\lipsum[1]\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

YYY

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

I would really like to be able to use the new system since a bug in using autofakeslant in lualatex has been solved there.

The old system has:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013062821 (rev 4627)  (format=lualatex 2014.1.3)  11 FEB 2016 13:00
Package: fontspec 2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Package: fontspec-patches 2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
Package: fontspec-luatex 2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
Package: flowfram 2014/09/30 v1.17 (NLCT)
```

But the new system has:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (rev 5238)  (format=lualatex 2015.12.23)  11 FEB 2016 11:21
Package: fontspec 2015/09/24 v2.4e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Package: fontspec-patches 2015/09/24 v2.4e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
Package: fontspec-luatex 2015/09/24 v2.4e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
Package: flowfram 2014/09/30 v1.17 (NLCT)
```

New:

[image]

Old:

[image]

Comment: On page 2, using texlive I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8eRmF.png) is that what you see?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I see in the incorrect output from the new system. In the old system it looks like [this](http://imgur.com/QdiuYFx) and that is what I would like to get.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is neither miktex (texlive 2015 has the same problem) nor lualatex (pdflatex shows it too). In texlive 2014 it works, but if one add \usepackage{fixltx2e} then it breaks. So some of the changes added to the format are responsable ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ooh interesting. I wonder who I could blame for that :(  Got to dash will look later if no one else answered

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It is the change in the `\@startdblcolumn` definition. And you could blame Nicola ;-). After all flowframe redefines \@outputdblcol.

Comment: I reported this here http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bug-report.cgi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need this:

```
% you probably don't need this \RequirePackage{luatex85}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[draft]{flowfram}

% 1sp makes a lot of difference
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@dblfloatplacement{\def\f@depth{1sp}}
\makeatother


\ffvadjustfalse
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\makedfheaderfooter
\Ncolumn{3}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setdynamiccontents*{header}{Test}

\begin{document}
\show\colon

\lipsum[1-8]

XXX

\begin{figure}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}\lipsum[1]\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

YYY

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion. Following Ulrike Fischer's comment, I saw as a potential strategy to restore the 1996 definition of \@startdblcolumn but this looks much nicer. I am away from the computer where I am testing the new system so I will confirm tomorrow whether it solves my problem.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed 5.36 nanometers with magical properties.